# Integrating with MS Exchange without a local copy of Exchange?

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need to write a component to retrieve emails from a given Exchange Server account. I don't have a local copy of Exchange and I can't easily get access to the production server. What options do I have? Is there a cut down / free development version of Exchange? Is there an API that I can code against and then just deploy and test in live?

Answer (score 1):

You can download a 120 day evaluation version of Exchange 2010 from http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/en-us/try-it.aspx

Threre is also a link on that page to set up a test against an online version

Answer (score 1):

Without having a staging and/or test environment with another instance of exchange running, you might be out of luck.

I would also approach this from a design stand-point.  You likely want to test your logic independently of Exchange (i.e. you don't want to test Exchange and you may want to test code that uses your code that interfaces with Exchange but don't necessarily want to re-test the code that interfaces with Exchange--and take the performance his of a round-trip to/from Exchange).  So, I would look at Dependency Inversion and mocking as a means of separating your code from being directly dependant on a existing, available, and operational instance of exchange running.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can simulate it (as far as I know via 3rd party apps that is), however you can sign-up for the free [Office 365 beta](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/small-business/beta.aspx) (or any other hosted exchange trials) point your Visual Studio to

`http://[whatever pod hosting your mailbox].outlook.com/ews/Exchange.asmx`

add it as a WebService reference and get on with your development. Best of luck.